# Map Ubuntu Drive Onto WIndows Vista

Tags: networking, mount, windows, samba, windows-vista

I would like to be able to map my Ubuntu 16.04 drive onto a Windows Vista machine without Samba. I have been able to map two drives to Vista so far but cannot figure out how to map Ubuntu. (Windows 7 drive and external network drive) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply right-clicking the folder, selecting share and ticking the appropriated settings, then logging out or restarting should do it. If it's still not visible in Vista that's a problem in that OS and completely off-topic here.

Comment: I have tried this. This option requires Samba. When I do this it tells me that I need Samba and if I want to install it. I select yes, it tries to install and then says "Package Operation Failed".

Comment: So your problem is of a different nature: broken packages and/or something wrong with your software sources. However, that isn't reflected in your question. Otherwise I would have said first of all fix it and install samba. If it still doesn't work then - and only then - we start troubleshooting samba.

Comment: I do not want to use Samba. I would rather find a different way to map Ubuntu to Vista. Although when I did run "sudo apt-get install -f" it returned at the end "Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Comment: There are alternatives for other OSes and most are better then samba but not for Windows, as far as I know. If other users have other suggestions I'm all for it and eager to learn something new.

Comment: @SirLemaGrag Please edit your question. It's not very clear what you are asking. If you are trying to get samba to work, please post your smb.conf, so people have a chance to help you with configuring Samba.